# I try to install a .deb, when I double click I get: the file "filename" could not be opened

Tags: nvidia, debian, debian-installer

I also try to use the command prompt on the desktop directory, but it states permission denied. Who is denying permission? I am the only user on my computer.

Comment: @msPeachy A `.deb` file is not an executable and cannot be run as one regardless of its permissions or the identity of the user trying to execute it.

Answer (score 4):

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

in the filename you have to place the filename of your `.deb` file.

Comment: has got correct command. even you can right click the file and select open with software centre or synaptic package manager.

Comment: terminal is the fast way ,so i have suggest that .

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (by pressing CTLR+ALT+T) and then change to the directory where the .deb file is.
Assuming that the .deb file is in the Downloads folder, type this:

```
cd Downloads
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg -i your_file_name.deb
```

If dpkg prompts you for something, just type Y (which stands for "yes"). After that, your package should have been installed correctly.

Answer (score -1):

for .deb packages use **dpkg -i *filename***

Comment: `dpkg -i ...` must be run as `root` (so it needs `sudo`). Furthermore, changing permissions on a `.deb` file does not make it executable (a `.deb` is *not* a program or script), and does not make it possible to install it without `sudo`.