# Install .deb files without any Internet

Tags: installation, drivers, internet

I want to install `ndiskgtk` and whenever I click the `.deb` file, it gets me through the Software Center. I don't have any Internet so I can't install it. Will this method above work? I am 13 years old, so I'm not really that smart with Linux. I want to install ndiskgtk (I think that's what it's called) so that I can get internet to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I try to install a .deb, when I double click I get: the file "filename" could not be opened](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169481/i-try-to-install-a-deb-when-i-double-click-i-get-the-file-filename-could-no)

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal (by pressing <kbd>CTLR</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and then change to the directory where the .deb file is. Assuming that the .deb file is in the Downloads folder, type this in terminal:

```
cd Downloads
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg -i your_file_name.deb
```

If dpkg prompts you for something, just type Y (which stands for "yes"). After that, your package should have been installed correctly.

I hope this helps.